# How to reliably maintain a desktop session while running selenium node on windows VM?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3, virtualmachine, ie, selenium-grid

I run a grid on Windows VM's in hyper-V. On hub host vm, I use [Remote Desktop connection manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) to open Desktop sessions, otherwise webdrivers do not function correctly.

But RDCMan is not a reliable tool, and running headless browser is not an option for **IE** and **Edge**. What is the best practice to run nodes on remote windows VMs?
Is there a reliable solution available to maintain a desktop session while node is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable method I've found is to configure the VMs to auto-logon with an administrator-level login and disable screensaver and user access control. This effectively means that whenever the vm is on, it is logged on and there is a desktop session running.

You may need to convince your employer's network management people to let you do this for the test system virtual machines, and you might need a few go-rounds before any group policy changes fully take (I certainly did), but once that's done and the VMs are properly configured, you should have no further issues.

This [Windows support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) describes how to configure automatic log on.

Comment: auto-logon on network accessible machines is against IT policy in my company. They won't allow it, so this option will not work.

Comment: That limits your options a lot - if your IT group isn't prepared to do something along the lines of a fenced subnet where your automation system is isolated and has few others able to access it, you may be limited to building a login script into the VM initialization or containerizing the VM. Both are more complicated.

Comment: I was able to convince IT to use Auto-Logon on Test VMs. This actually worked out pretty good.